# I have a varchar field that I want part of the string removed

Tags: mysql

In mySQL I have several records that I am trying to delete part of a string. 
For instance USERNAME contains `joesomebody@somewhere.com`

I want to remove the `@` and everything after it (ie `@somewhere.com`) and then update the USERNAME with that string.

`joesomebody@somewhere.com` becomes `joesomebody`

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you do that easily using `LOCATE` to get the position of the `@` and `SUBSTR` or `LEFT` to get everything before that?

Comment: The MySQL documentation has a nice page with a list of all the string functions. It seems like you couldn't have spent any time looking at it before writing this question. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: No. Didnt locate the answer until now.  my SQL man died and needed a quick fix since he didn't finish a project.

Answer (score 0):

```
update your_table
set email = substring(email, 1, instr(email, '@')-1)
where instr(email, '@') > 0
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/5048)

Comment: Thanks.  One of our guys had a stroke and there are a few things he left behind.  I know this was probably pretty simple to you and i appreciate your help.